# Text Game Closes after every command - NOTE: I just started out

Tags: python, loops

```
print "Welcome to the game. In the game you can 'look around' and 'examine things'."
print "There is also some hidden actions.
print "You wake up."

input = raw_input("> ")

haveKey = False
applesExist = True



if input == "look around":
print "You are in a dusty cell. There is a barrel in the corner of the room, an unmade bed,"
print "a cabinet and chest. There is also a cell door."
elif haveKey == False and input == "use door":
print "The door is locked."
elif haveKey == True and input == "use door":
print "You open the door and immediately gets shot with an arrow. You won, kinda."
elif input == "examine barrel":
print "There is apples in the barrel."
elif applesExist == True and input == "eat apple":
print "Mmmmh, that was yummy! But now there are no apples left..."
applesExist = False
elif applesExist == False and input == "eat apple":
print "sury, u et al aples befur!!1111"
elif input == "examine bed":
print "The bed is unmade, and has very dusty sheets. This place really needs a maid."
elif input == "sleep on bed":
print "You lie down and try to sleep, but you can't because of all the bugs crawling on you."
elif input == "examine chest":
print "There is a key in the chest."
elif input == "take key":
haveKey = True
print "You take the key."
elif input == "examine cabinet":
print "The cabinet is made of dark oak wood. There is a endless cup of tea in it."
elif input == "drink tea":
print "You put some tea in your mouth, but immediately spit it out."
print "It seems it has been here for quite some time."
else:
print "Huh, what did you say? Didn't catch that."
```

No syntax errors, no errors of any kind. Not. One. 
The problem is that after I examine, look around and eat apples the
game closes. How do I fix this? With a While loop?

plz halp

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously very beginner, I won't hammer you about how to do the best architecture.  Get used to write code a little first.

If you want to **repeat** an action, that means a loop (here it's called the main game loop).  You code currently takes an input, do a lot of checks to do an action on it, do that action and then... reach the end of the file and stops.

If you wan to go back to the input, you need to enclose all the code you want to repeat in a repetitive code structure, i.e. a loop.

Here is a basic pseudo-code of a game main loop.

```
playing=True:
while playing:
   instruction = takeUserInputOfSomeForm();
   if instruction == something:
       doStuff()
   # etc ...
   elif instruction == "quit":
       playing=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop otherwise when the code hits the bottom of the file Python will exit. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm